# Limit when remote uploading

Tags: upload, vps, vesta

I have problem with remote uploading file from my vesta VPS to uptobox.com. I have mp4 file on my VPS. I want to upload that file on my uptobox account. I use remote upload.

File size is 1.4 GB, I move file to public_html so it can be accessed via link ex. http://domain.com/file.mp4

I paste link in uptobox remote upload field and upload starts. When upload reach 1 GB it says that file is uploaded. But there is uploaded just 1 GB of 1.4 GB, not whole file.

I tried to remote upload on other services, I tried with different files - same thing ... it just stops at 1 GB. It is not limit on that services (I have premium accounts) it's limit in my vestacp configuration.

Now I have to change that limit, but I don't know what to change.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved.

There was limit in nginx settings ...

Added

proxy_max_temp_file_size 5000m;

in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf so now can download files size up to 5 gb per file.